# Programacion en php

Tags: php

Una pregunta por aqui lo que pasa es que tengo un problema para poder subir el archivo pero no me lo sube estoy haciendo por medio de PUT donde obtengo toda la imagen codificada pero lo logro subir la imagen, en donde PUT es donde tiene la imagen pero no puedo subir la imagen al servidor.

Este es mi codigo me pueden orientar:

```
if ('PUT' === $method) {                
    $_PUT = file_get_contents('php://input');
    //  var_dump($_PUT); 

    $tmp_namee = '<input type="hidden" name="PNG" value="512000"/>';

     //$_PUT;
     //$tmp_name;

    // var_dump("hola file".$_FILES['File']['name']);
    $dest = $_PUT;
    $tmp_name = $tmp_namee;
    uploadfile($dest, $tmp_name);

      $subir_archivo = $directorio.basename($_FILES['PNG']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['PNG']['tmp_name'] , $subir_archivo)) {
          echo "El archivo es válido y se cargó correctamente.<br><br>";
       } else {`introducir el código aquí`
           echo "La subida ha fallado";
       }
    }`introducir el código aquí`
```